# How to print message at control panel when vscode extension running

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to print or output message at the control panel or terminal panel when I using vscode extension? the extension is developed by me.Now only use `vscode.window.showErrorMessage` to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

```
const out = vscode.window.createOutputChannel("test running");
out.show();
out.appendLine('hello');
```